# while installing zetadocs archive service

Tags: navision

I am getting this error while I am able to open the database but still I am getting this error
Error 27506.Error executing SQL script CreateDatabase.sql. Line 20. The server principal "PUPRODUCTION\kumarchan" is not able to access the database "ZetadocsArchive" under the current security context. (916)

Answer (score 0):

because Zetadocs Archive is a separate SQL Database your user don't have access to it. 
Alter you SQL permissions (probably you don't have enough permission to create databases)

You can find lots of information on the official website: [HOWTO: Install the Zetadocs Archive](http://www.equisys.com/technotes/ztn4299.htm) or just Google for "ZetadocsArchive" [link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ZetadocsArchive)

Cheers!